# Which is the best way to handle the SOAP response in Android

Tags: android, parsing, soap

I am using the KSoap2 for communicating with the server. The communication is fine and returns a set of values that i have mentioned below. I am not sure with the way i am handling the response. I wrote a separate java class that implements ***KvmSerializable***  for mapping the ***XML*** objects with the java objects. After a long research in the web, i found the use of the parser like ***SAX***, ***DOM*** ..etc is more standard and flexible.

Is there any way i can bring the SAX for parsing the following response... if so,please provide some references..

This is the response that i got after i send a request to the server from my android client app. Please note, This response is not ended with .xml / returns as a .xml file.

This is the webclient response :

http://134.1.10.5/Maxima/MaximaSystem.asmx/ValidateLogin

```
<DataSet>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Table">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="UserIcode" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="UserUserName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="UserPassword" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="UserTypeICode" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ProfileTable" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="UserTypeDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>

<diffgr:diffgram>

<NewDataSet>
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<Name>Frecan </Name>
<UserIcode>634</UserIcode>
<UserUserName>dairy</UserUserName>
<UserPassword>dairy123</UserPassword>
<UserTypeICode>632</UserTypeICode>
<ProfileTable/>
<UserTypeDesc>Dentist</UserTypeDesc>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

This is the response. No XML Tags ...anything...Please suggest the best way that i can parse it using the native parser of Android. If so, Please provide some references.

This is the sample of the response that i get, when i ping server through Android Client

```
 anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=an
 yType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{....
 // some values ........
 };
 element=anyType{};
 element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{};     element=anyType{}; 
 element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; };unique=anyType{selector=anyType{};
 field=anyType{};}; }; }; diffgram=anyType{}; }
```

Please let me know, is it possible to use native parsers in Android.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

    if(result != null){

        int count = result.getPropertyCount();
        //TextView t = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.resultbox);
        //t.setText("SOAP response:\n\n" + count);

        SoapObject nameResult = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
        // TextView t = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.resultbox);
        //t.setText("SOAP response:\n\n" + nameResult.toString());

        SoapObject test = (SoapObject) nameResult.getProperty(1);
        // TextView t = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.resultbox);
        // t.setText("SOAP response:\n\n" + test.toString());

        SoapObject dar = (SoapObject) test.getProperty(0);
        //TextView t = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.resultbox);
        //t.setText("SOAP response:\n\n" + dar.toString());

        SoapObject suvas = (SoapObject) dar.getProperty(0);
        int c = dar.getPropertyCount();
        TextView t = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.resultbox);
        t.setText("SOAP response:\n\n" + suvas.toString());
        //t.setText("SOAP response:\n\n" + c);
        //SoapObject nivas = (SoapObject) suvas.getProperty(NewsId);
        //TextView t = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.resultbox);
        // t.setText("SOAP response:\n\n" + nivas.toString());

    }
```

First you have to get a soap response in soapObject and then after that count the total property.

After getting count, please check one by one in which property you have your data ,
you can also implement an inner loop.